# Завис интерфейс доступа ILo (web)

Tags: linux

Завис ILO интерфейс, сервер находится в боевом режиме, через веб не запускается, но захожу через ssh, подскажите как можно рестартануть ilo, если требуется через директорию cd /map1, то пишет

```
cd map1 
sh: cd: can't cd to map1
```

подскажите, как можно перезапустить ilo?

Comment: http://h20564.www2.hpe.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=mmr_kc-0115524

Comment: там используются утилиты HP, у меня Сервер STSS Flagman HXQ226.2 Supermicro

Answer (score 0):

Увы, наглухо отвисший iLO исправляется только физическим отрубанием сервера из розетки.

Если это блейд-система, тогда чуть проще - это можно сделать удаленно, через админку блейда.